# How to swipe/slide go into the 3D Object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have done small demo in ARKit. i am facing problem with how to go inside 3D object by swiping.

For example, i have home 3D object, its working with Tap Gesture, Rotation Gesture, i would like to go inside home by swiping one to another room inside home 3D object.

Its rotating whole 3D object node, i could not able to swipe and go inside home..

This is the code i used for rotate based Y axis,

```
@objc private func viewRotated(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

    guard let node = node(at: location) else { return }

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        originalRotation = node.eulerAngles
    case .changed:
        guard var originalRotation = originalRotation else { return }
        originalRotation.y -= Float(gesture.rotation)
        node.eulerAngles = originalRotation
    default:
        originalRotation = nil
    }
}
```

To rotate in all direction using UIPanGestureRecognizer, this is the code i have added,

```
  @objc func viewPanned(gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = gestureRecognize.translation(in: gestureRecognize.view!)

    let x = Float(translation.x)
    let y = Float(-translation.y)

    let anglePan = sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2))*(Float)(M_PI)/180.0

    var rotationVector = SCNVector4()
    rotationVector.x = -y
    rotationVector.y = x
    rotationVector.z = 0
    rotationVector.w = anglePan

    homeNode?.rotation = rotationVector


    if(gestureRecognize.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
        //
        let currentPivot = homeNode?.pivot
        let changePivot = SCNMatrix4Invert( (homeNode?.transform)!)

        homeNode?.pivot = SCNMatrix4Mult(changePivot, currentPivot!)

        homeNode?.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity
    }
}
```

Perhaps there is another way of doing this, Can someone suggest a way..Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean swipe to rotate?

Comment: hi..thanks for your response, its mean not rotating the whole object, just rotate to go into next room inside Home(3D object).